# auto generate callback class at duplex /WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, binding

I'm trying to set duplex service.
I have created 2 interfaces:
the first - the interface which the server implement:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IBackUpServiceCallback))]
public interface IBackUpService
```

with some methods which are implement by the serve
and the second one:

```
public interface IBackUpServiceClient
```

which holds methods that the server is supposed to use when callback the client.
The implement class name

```
 BackUpServiceCallBack : IBackUpServiceClient
```

is at the client side.

The problem is - after I am adding the service - the compiler auto generate:

```
interface IBackUpServiceCallback
```

and demand me to implement it.
and i have 2 callback interfaces.
the first which i have implemented (`BackUpServiceClalBack`) at the client side, and the second one name :IBackUpServiceCallback - and I cant control it (client Url is "tempuri..")

and even if  `BackUpServiceClalBack` implements `IBackUpServiceCallback` - it doesn't get to the implement method during runtime.

I am working with wsDualHttpBinding Binding.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i figure out that i dont have to do "add service reference' at all.
and becuse the client know's the Interface at design time i can use it.

now i wont have a genareted code calss.
as well insted of Proxy i will use :

```
    private DuplexChannelFactory<IBackUpService> factory;
    private IBackUpService _proxy;
    InstanceContext t = new InstanceContext(implementClass);
    factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IBackUpService>(t, "nameOfBinding");

    _proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
```

and the binding itself will be at runtime.

Comment: Congrats on the fix.  When you are able, please mark your answer as 'accepted' using the checkmark to the left.  This will show others that your problem has been solved.  Cheers~